# Can we store google MLKit translation model in Bundle?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, firebase-mlkit, google-mlkit

I used google MLKit translation model in my app for translation and it is work as except after downloading required language package from the app.

As user point of view I want to reduce there time for downloading and make them quick available with app launch therefore, I want to store all MLKit model the app bundle itself. Is there a way I can do in NSBundle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible with the current version of the API. Best you can do is trigger the download of the language packs you require at first start of the app, through the model manager. We are considering official support for bundling language packs with the app, but have no committed plan just yet.

Comment: Once official support for bundling language packs with the app will be done then please update your post here that helps other users too. thanks!